# Modal Dialog in Autohosted Sp2013 App

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, modal-dialog

I am stuck with a problem and thought that maybe one of you can help me with it.

I have a autohosted Sharepoint App. The app consists of several aspx pages. 
What I want to do is that one of the pages is the Main page and there are buttons for the other pages. If the user clicks on one of them, the according aspx opens in a modal dialog. 
So the users nevery really leaves the Main page.

I tried it using this script:

```
 $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.Runtime.js',
       function () {
           $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.js',
               function () { $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', Showdialog); }
           );
       }
   );

function Showdialog() {

    var options = {
        url: "/_layouts/15/InDialog.aspx",
        tite: 'Sharing  Information',
        allowMaximize: false,
        showClose: true,
        width: 430,
        height: 230
    };

    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
    return false;
```

But all i get is a SOD is undefined exception when i execute this code.

What am I missing?

thanks in advance

best regards

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the **Autohosted app** you haven't the standard SharePoint libs because it's hosted on Azure. So you haven't any SOD or js files that usually you can use with a **SharePoint hosted app**

That means that you have to create your modal dialog window

Comment: Aha ok, makes sense thought. So I have to create a modal dialog with for example JQuery and display my page in it...? best regards

Comment: yes. You can use some libs to do that, like jquery.ui